# How to set a certain scene if object fall below a value?

Tags: game-engine

I would like to set a certain scene if a certain object falls to below zero or less.

This is the current aspect of my script:

```
import bge

# get the controller
controller = bge.logic.getCurrentController()

# get the game object that the controller is attached to.
obj = controller.owner

# get actuator attached to the controller named switchScene
act = controller.actuators["switchScene"]

# Detects player's z position is equal or minor then zero
if obj.worldPosition.z <= 0

# set scene name
act.scene = "Main"
```

This is the error that the terminal returns:

```
Python error compiling script - object 'Player', controller 'Python.003':
  File "Z.py", line 13
    if obj.worldPosition.z <= 0
                              ^
 SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You have a syntax error because you forgot the double point at the end of if statement.
2. You can change state of an actuator with current controller actívate or deactivate.

Your script should look like this:

```
import bge

# get the controller
controller = bge.logic.getCurrentController()

# get the game object that the controller is attached to.
obj = controller.owner

# get actuator attached to the controller named switchScene
act = controller.actuators["switchScene"]

# Detects player's z position is equal or minor then zero
if obj.worldPosition.z <= 0:
    # set scene name
    act.scene = "Main"
    # scene actuator mode: change to = 0
    act.mode = 0
    #change scene
    controller.activate(act)
```

Related : [Python API controller.activate](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bge.types.SCA_PythonController.html?highlight=controller%20activate#bge.types.SCA_PythonController.activate), [Python API KX_SceneActuator](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bge.types.KX_SceneActuator.html?highlight=scene#bge.types.KX_SceneActuator.scene)

**EDIT**

Hi again.

About chicOrtiz comentary:

That **error** its because you **dont have an actuator named "switchScene"** conected to the current controller in the **logic editor** window (panel). as shown in the next image:

[image]

So i decide to make a blend example and found our next error.

We need to set actuator mode before set the scene. So the script should be:

```
import bge

# get the controller
controller = bge.logic.getCurrentController()

# get the game object that the controller is attached to.
obj = bge.logic.getCurrentScene().objects["Cube"]

# get actuator attached to the controller named switchScene
act = controller.actuators["lascene"]

# Detects player's z position is equal or minor then zero

if obj.worldPosition.z <= 0:
    # set actuator mode : 
    # 0 = ?restart? ;   1 = ?restart?? ; 
    # 2 = set Scene ;   3 = set camera ; 
    # 4 = overlay   ;   5 = underlay
    act.mode = 2
    #set camera, it has to be in the same scene.
    act.camera = bge.logic.getCurrentScene().objects["Camera_main_scene.001"]
    #Set actuator Scene   
    act.scene = "Second_Scene"
    #active actuator
    controller.activate(act)
```

[image]

**Note:** About if you need to use bpy or bge,

**if you want a game always use bge**

**if you want animation movie, addon, etc use bpy**

**bpy and bge cant work together in anyway** (in my understanding)

**bpy only used inside blender (internal, cycles) dont bge**

Comment: Thank you @strapicarus. Now I'm getting the following error: `code` Python script error - object 'Player', controller 'Python.003':
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Z.py", line 10, in <module>
KeyError: 'requested item "switchScene" does not exist' `code` What should I use? (https://docs.blender.org/api/2.78b/bpy.types.SceneActuator.html?highlight=scene%20actuator#bpy.types.SceneActuator.scene) or (https://docs.blender.org/api/2.78b/bge.types.KX_SceneActuator.html?highlight=scene%20actuator#bge.types.KX_SceneActuator.scene)?

Comment: Hi @chicOrtiz plz read the edit answer, at the final i leave a link to blend example.

Comment: Hi Strapicurus! Thank you very much for the solution. Interesting to see how the numbers 0 or 1 can both restart the scene in your second script ;) I even tried something like "-23" and it seems to restart the scene too... Go figure! :)

Comment: did you test the blend file? or just copy the script, the scene will restart if something wrong like the names. the `act.camera` only work if use `act.mode = 3` and have 2 or more cameras in the same scene. if you download the blend press P and the scenes should change from Main_Scene(active) to Second_Scene(inactive)

Comment: Yes! Sure I tested the Blender File, it works perfectly, thanks. Just pointing out some interesting findings that are a mystery to me ;)